# how to draw a pie chart in objective C

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

Can please somebody help me with some code or a framework for drawing a pie chart on the iPhone or iPad? Even documentation on how to approach the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard good things about [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Answer (score 3):

Besides the proposed library in the other answers, there are two really good open source pie chart classes that I used. They look very nice, are extremely simple, have a look at them at GitHub:

- [XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart)
- [NBPieChart](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty)

Answer (score 0):

how about using a WebView and SVG? I do not recall which developer (of a popular app) described how he used SVG to create plots.